# showing/hiding a div on click pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have JavaScript code that is not working. What I want is very simple, I want to show/hide a child div when parent is clicked. But I want to do it in pure JavaScript without using jQuery or any other libraries. here is my JavaScript code:

```js
    function addCal(){

   var inDate=document.getElementById("date_in");
   if(inDate.childNodes.length<2)
    {
        var inCal= document.createElement("div");
        inCal.id="inCal";
        var inText= document.createTextNode("Hello");
        inCal.appendChild(inText);
        inDate.appendChild(inCal); 

       } else 
         {
       return false;
         }

    }

    function removeCal(){

  var inCal=document.getElementById("inCal");

  if(inCal)
   {
  inCal.parentNode.removeChild(inCal);
   } else 
    {
  return false;
    }

    }
    document.getElementById("date_in").addEventListener("click", addCal);

    document.getElementById("date_in").addEventListener("click",removeCal);
```

```html
    <div id="date_in"><input type="date" name="date_in"/></div>
    <div id="dat_out"><input type="date" name="date_out"/></div>
    
    <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I have placed the javaScript code near the closing body tag. Can anyone please suggest why is this code not working or any better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Seems to work, unless I don't understand what exactly is the part that doesn't...

Comment: it simply doesn't work, I have checked the console but no errors or warnings.

Comment: try adding code in onload function

Comment: @minitech: as I mentioned, I want to achieve hide and show functionality, how can I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve added both `addCal` and `removeCal` as listeners to the same event. When clicked, `addCal` will be called, and `removeCal` will undo what it did immediately afterwards. Consider adding one listener that decides which function to call based on the presence of `inCal`.

```
function addCal() {
    var inDate = document.getElementById("date_in");
    var inCal = document.createElement("div");
    inCal.id = "inCal";
    var inText = document.createTextNode("Hello");
    inCal.appendChild(inText);
    inDate.appendChild(inCal);
}

function removeCal() {
    var inCal = document.getElementById("inCal");
    inCal.parentNode.removeChild(inCal);
}

document.getElementById("date_in").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var inCal = document.getElementById("inCal");

    if (inCal) {
        removeCal();
    } else {
        addCal();
    }
});
```